# What does the "t" in int32_t signify?

Tags: c, type-systems, data-types, etymology

In C, what meaning, if any does the `t` at the end of integer types like `uint8_t` and `int32_t` have? Where did it originate? Why wasn't the type just called `int32`?

Comment: Probably stands for "type".

Comment: The question is a duplicate of [What does a type followed by _t (underscore-t) represent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent)

Comment: @mguassa duplicates must be on the same site. But it is good to have that signpost to link the two questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because all identifiers ending with `_t` are reserved for future additional types.

The `int32_t` family of types was added in the C99 standard, so they used the reserved names to avoid conflict with already existing software.

You can find a nice overview of reserved names [in the glibc documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html).

---

Note:
Since Microsoft is not the C standards committee, they are right in not using the `_t` family of names, opting for the unreserved `INT32` instead.

Comment: For what standard C doesn't reserve ending in `_t`, POSIX reserves the rest.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `INT32` predated `int32_t`.

Comment: @StevenBurnap That may be correct, I don't know. But that is not really important. Important is the fact that `_t` types are reserved, and the fact that `int32_t` is in the standard while `INT32` is not.

Comment: My point is just that Microsoft chose `INT32` because there was no standard alternative when it did so and now has to keep it for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 8):

At the time the C99 Standard was ratified, there already existed countless C programs that used `int32` as an identifier.  On platforms where both `int` and `long` were 32 bits, some of that pre-existing code would have defined `int32` as `int` and some as `long` (the latter allows compatibility with platforms where `int` is 16 bits but `long` is 32; the former allows compatibility with platforms where `int` is 32 bits but `long` is 64).  While it might have made sense for compilers to allow "int" and "long" to by synonymous on platforms where they're both 32 bits and have matching representations, in which case the "new" `int32` type could compatible with both, the Standard doesn't allow for that.

Code written for a platform where `int32` is known to be synonymous with `int` can use `int*` and `int32*` interchangeably.  Code written for a platform where `int32` is known to be synonymous with `long` can use `int32*` and `long*` interchangeably.  Even on platforms where both `int` and `long` have identical representations, however, the Standard requires platforms squawk if an attempt is made to convert an `int*` to `long*` or vice versa without a cast.

Further, even on platforms where `int` and `long` have the same representation, casting an `int*` to a `long*` is not required to yield a pointer that's usable as a `long*`; the current maintainers of gcc believe that since the Standard doesn't require that such a cast work, their compiler should generate code where such casts sometimes fail.

Thus, if C99 had used `int32` rather than `int32_t`, it would have had to break code that defines that identifier as `int` and expects it to be synonymous with `int`, or code that defines that defines that identifier as `long` and expects it to be synonymous with `long`.

Answer (score 4):

The _t data types are typedef types in the stdint.h header, while int is a built-in fundamental data type to C. The _t datatypes are only available if stdint.h exists. The fundamental data types like `int`, however, are guaranteed to exist.

Basically, it really doesn't mean much of anything. It's just how C decided to name things.

Answer (score 3):

size_t is read as 'size type'

_t usually means type, and sometimes typedef.

> Why wasn't the type just called int32

So it could be distinguished from a built in type, stdint.h is supposed to choose the proper built in type to be the given size depending on the platform. N.b. some compilers int32_t aliases a compiler specific notation like i_32 or something similar.

Microsoft took a different approach and their standard is based on #defines, with values like INT32, DWORD, etc.